# Why isn't my array adding character's into it?

Tags: java, arrays

The class below has the main method (shortened)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int size, command;
        char inputChar;
        String inputString;
    size = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a size for the array"));
    CharacterList list1 = new CharacterList(size);

    inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a character to add");
                    inputChar = inputString.charAt(0);
                    boolean added;

                    added = list1.addCharacter(inputChar);

                    if(added == true)
                    {
                        System.out.println(inputChar + " was added");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println(inputChar + " was not added");
                    }
}
```

I would like to add the characters which the user types in an array (size given by the user). And, if the size is not enough I want to double the size and add copy all the previous array elements in the new array and assign the old array to the new array (referencing).
Output:
Size of the array: 3
a was added
[a, , ,]
b was added
[a,b, ]
c was added
[a, b,  ,  ,  ,  ]

```
public class CharacterList {

    private char [] charArray;
    private int count;

private void doubleArrayCapacity() {

        //create new array of char, which is double length
        char [] newCharArray = new char[this.charArray.length*2];
        //prescribe values from old array to new one
        for(int i=0; i<this.charArray.length-1; i++) {
            newCharArray[i] = this.charArray[i];
        }
        //set newCharArray set new value of your field charArray
        this.charArray = newCharArray;
    }
public int indexOf(char searchingChar) {

        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {

            if(charArray[i] == searchingChar){
                return i;
            }

        }
        return -1;

    }

public boolean addCharacter(char characterToAdd){

        if(indexOf(characterToAdd) == -1){

            if(count == charArray.length -1){
                doubleArrayCapacity();
            }

            for(int i = 0; i<charArray.length; i++){

                if(charArray[i] == ' '){

                    charArray[i] = characterToAdd;
                    break;
                }
            }
            count++;
            return true;

        } else
            return false;

    }
}
```

The class above has the other class

I would like to save all the elements typed by the user and also double the space without affecting my elements.

Thank you

Comment: @Joni The characters are not getting added, once I double the array size. Why is not happening?

Comment: @Priya it's not even compiling, what does indexOf(char) do in CharacterList#addCharacter cause it's not declared in any way.

Comment: @abc It returns -1 or the position of the array. (I didn't add that method)

Answer (score 0):

The way your `addCharacter` method is written, it needs that the character array is filled with space characters `' '`. But `doubleArrayCapacity` is not adding spaces. You can add the space characters with a loop, like this:

```
private void doubleArrayCapacity() {

    //create new array of char, which is double length
    char [] newCharArray = new char[this.charArray.length*2];
    //prescribe values from old array to new one
    for(int i=0; i<this.charArray.length-1; i++) {
        newCharArray[i] = this.charArray[i];
    }

    // FILL REST OF NEW ARRAY WITH WHITE SPACE
    for(int i=this.charArray.length; i < newCharArray.length; i++) {
        newCharArray[i] = ' ';
    }

    //set newCharArray set new value of your field charArray
    this.charArray = newCharArray;
}
```

By the way it would help if you posted the full source code so we don't have to guess what the constructors and methods do.